# does android have the <defaultsMap> xml tag that firebase uses?

Tags: java, android, xml

in firebase you can provide it a defaultsMap xml tag for keeping something like key value pairs. it looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- START xml_defaults -->
<defaultsMap>
    <entry>
        <key>loading_phrase</key>
        <value>Fetching config…</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>welcome_message_caps</key>
        <value>false</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>welcome_message</key>
        <value>Welcome to my awesome app!</value>
    </entry>
</defaultsMap>
    <!-- END xml_defaults -->
```

my question is NOT firebase related. My question is am i able to utilize this for other purposes ? i'd like to keep a defaultsMap in xml for other purposes and it wold even be so handy if i could convert it to a java Map easily. Is this tag only for firebase use ?  If not how would i use it for my own purposes ? i cant find any documentation on the tag, seems poorly documented.

Comment: Not sure if this answers but you can use `Resources.getXml(R.xml.name)` to parse the xml

Comment: yes of course. then i can use  XmlPullParser to parse it. i guess i can use any tags i want then not just defaultsMap, i could make up my own right ? you've given me the acceptable answer by the way.

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Resources.getXml(R.xml.name)` to parse any generic xml. So yes you could make up your own as well. However, there's something you should keep in mind

> The XmlPullParser implementation returned here has some limited functionality. In particular, you can't change its input

taken from [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int))